# How to use data contained in several related database tables for a form letter?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, mail-merge, libreoffice-base

I want to create a form letter with *LibreOffice Writer*. The data is contained in a *LibreOffice Base* database, **in several tables**.

I followed the guide [Creating a Form Letter](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Creating_a_Form_Letter). It seems that **I can only select *one* table** of a database.

Is there a way to use data which is contained in several (related) tables in a form letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you could create a ***[Query](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Queries)*** that combines the data from the different tables. Then, just set the Query as address list "table" in the mail merge wizard. In the Mail Merge Wizard, "table" doesn't mean the same as in LO Base. Also a query may act as "table".

This seems to be complicated, but combining different tables is a typical database task - so it makes sense to use the database tools to accomplish that task. Otherwise, you would have to handle the table JOIN from inside the mail merge wizard, which seems quite difficult to handle.